# Java method is successfully executed inside a Java agent, but fails if executed in a Java class in the database's code

Tags: xpages, jakarta-mail

In my XPages application, I use the `javax.mail` library to read mail messages from IMAP accounts. The class I use to get and save messages works perfectly fine if I use it inside a Java agent. However, if I put the exact same class into "Code/Java" in my XPages project, the methods throw  `javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for imaps` when I try to get the session store:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "AlwaysTrustSSLContextFactory");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.port", "993");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true"); 
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");
    URLName url = new URLName("imaps", server, 993, "", username, password);
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore(url); //THE ERROR OCCURS HERE
    store.connect();
```

The `javax.mail` library that I added to the project's build path is exactly the same that I use in the Java agent.

Some posts I found for the mentioned type of exception suggest that it might be caused by multiple versions of `javax.mail` being included in the build path. However, this does not seem to be the case because removing `javax.mail` from the build path causes the class to not be built.

Does anybody know what's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the versions and providers of *javax.mail* used. You can do this by adding

```
props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true" );
```

to your properties.

On the console (Client's Java Console or Server console  you can see the result, something like this:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4ea
```

and

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
```

Alternativly, you can get the list of available providers programmatically (when you have no console access):

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
Provider[] providers = session.getProviders();
for( Provider p:providers ){
    if( ! ("".equals(tmpStr)) )
        tmpStr = tmpStr + ",";
    tmpStr = tmpStr + p.getProtocol();
}
```

[You will see that the list of providers does not contain *imaps* on the server (8.5.3)]

Comment: Great tip - thanks very much. The debug property revealed that the JavaMail version on our domino 9.0.1 server is 1.3 . Deep in the bowels of the Notes directory I found 2 mail.jar libraries. As a test, I replaced both files on my **Notes Client**'s Notes directory (9.0.1) with the most recent version (JavaMail 1.5.2). Now the code is working there. However, I'm scared about also replacing the libraries on the **Domino server** because this might cause other problems with the mailing on the server. What do you think? Is it dangerous to replace the libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Was going to comment, but rep isn't high enough yet....

Is the java agent in the same db?

If it is, can you cut it and try the xpage when the agent isn't there?  Probably a long shot, but may be worth checking that the agent isn't interfering in any way.

Comment: Yes, the agent is in the same db, but this does not cause the problem. In the development process I created the Java class in "Code/Java" **before** I tried it with the Java agent. I just used the Java agent to check if there is a problem with the dependencies etc. To be totally sure, I just removed the agent from the database and, as expected, it still doesn't work. However, thanks for the advice.

Comment: No problem.  The other thing worth checking is the java permissions.  XPages have sepearte ones to java agents as I understand it.  Try modifying the java policy file to give permissions.  For TESTING PURPOSES ONLY you can grant all permissions like this:
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

Comment: Another good advice, but I already granted AllPermission in 2 java.policy files, namely the one in the Notes base directoy as well as the one in jvm\lib\security . Also, none of the lines in the stack trace for the NoSuchProviderException says anything about not having enough permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check out [my article](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-9FCMHJ?Open) with a code sample how to read IMAP from Notes. I didn't run that code as agent, but from the command line. Chances are, that it will work better for you. Main difference (possibly?): I used the [Google enhanced IMAP classes](https://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/).

Check it out and let us know if that worked for you!

Comment: Short question: Since your article is named "GMail2Notes..." I guess your code processes messages from GMail accounts "only", right? I'm asking because I need it to work for any IMAP server...

Comment: The code would work with any IMAP when you remove the Google specific parts which is the folder structure they use to represent labels and the call to get labels. The rest is same same.